# Netlink: sending from kernel to user - EAGAIN and ENOBUFS

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, netlink

I'm having a lot of trouble sending netlink messages from kernel module to userspace-daemon. They randomly fail. On the kernel side, the `genlmsg_unicast` fails with `EAGAIN` while on the user-side, `nl_recvmsgs_default` (function from `libnl`) fails with `NLE_NOMEM` which is caused by `recvmsg` syscall failing with `ENOBUFS`.

Netlink messages are small, maximum payload size is ~300B.

Here is the code for sending message from kernel:

```c
int send_to_daemon(void* msg, int len, int command, int seq, u32 pid) {
    struct sk_buff* skb;
    void* msg_head;
    int res, payload;

    payload = GENL_HDRLEN+nla_total_size(len)+36;
    skb = genlmsg_new(payload, GFP_KERNEL);
    msg_head = genlmsg_put(skb, pid, seq, &psvfs_gnl_family, 0, command);
    nla_put(skb, PSVFS_A_MSG, len, msg);
    genlmsg_end(skb, msg_head);
    genlmsg_unicast(&init_net, skb, pid);

    return 0;
}
```

I absolutely have no idea why this is happening and my project just won't work because of that! I really hope someone could help me with that.

Comment: why are you not checking the return values given by any of the genlmsg_* function. That should be your first step in recognizing which function is causing the problem.

Comment: I do check the values. `genlmsg_unicast` returns `-EAGAIN`, as I described above, while all other functions succeed. I just removed the checks from above code to make it shorter and show the logic itself.

Answer (score 3):

I was having a similar problem receiving ENOBUFS via recvmsg from a netlink socket.  I found that my problem was the kernel socket buffer filling before userspace could drain it.

From the [netlink(7) man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/netlink.7.html):

```
   However, reliable transmissions from kernel to user are impossible in
   any case.  The kernel can't send a  netlink  message  if  the  socket
   buffer  is  full:  the message will be dropped and the kernel and the
   user-space process will no longer have the same view of kernel state.
   It  is  up  to  the  application to detect when this happens (via the
   ENOBUFS error returned by recvmsg(2)) and resynchronize.
```

I addressed this problem by increasing the size of the socket receive buffer (setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, ...)
, or [nl_socket_set_buffer_size()](http://www.infradead.org/~tgr/libnl/doc/api/group__socket.html#gaec9b1f3b0fdbf4e6e0fb10a233b5df68) if you are using libnl).

Answer (score 2):

I wonder if you are running on a 64bits machine. If it is the case, I suspect that the use of an `int` as the type of `payload` can be the root of some issues as `genlmsg_new()` expects a `size_t` which is 64bits on x86_64.

Secondly, I don't think you need to add `GENL_HDRLEN` to `payload` as this is taken care of by `genlmsg_new()` (by using `genlmsg_total_size()`, which returns `genlmsg_msg_size()` which finally does the addition). Why this `+ 36` by the way? Does not look very portable nor explicit on what it is there for.

Hard to tell more without having a look at the rest of the code.

Comment: Thanks for your interest :)
I am running it on a 32bit machine. Either way, I don't think this is the case because my messages are very small (at most, let's say 1KB).
Payload computation in my code is a result of me not being able to figure out what exactly should I pass to `genlmsg_new`. If I don't add these 36 bytes, `nla_put` will fail. I know this is very ugly.
I will show some more code in my post. The whole code is here, if you are interested: https://github.com/ghik/PS (it's a bit ugly, but it's not going to be maintained or extended so it doesn't really matter).